# How specific should the OS tag be?

Tags: discussion, tags

What if I ask for a software running on Windows.

For instance I use Windows 7 64 bit Home Premium.

That means I could run almost any software since Windows 95. How should I tag my question? Just [Windows]? Or be very specific?

Comment: link: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/139/should-we-have-tags-for-separate-linux-distributions (same but for Linux)

Answer (score 11):

Be broader in the tag than in your question. Let's say I want (using the example Gilles tossed out) something very specific that runs on Windows 2000. I would apply  the [windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag to my question, then within the question itself:

> This has to be able to run on a 32 bit Windows 2000 setup, with 8MB of Ram powered by hamsters fed intravenously from an espresso machine.

You don't want to deviate too much from the parent tag, lest you end up with:

[hamsters](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hamsters) [espresso](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/espresso) [windows-2000](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-2000) [caffeine](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caffeine)

Natural tag curating will turn up needs to apply more precision in the OS tags, I have a feeling Ubuntu might want to separate from Linux, or BSD from Unix, or a bunch of other possibilities. For now, lets keep them as simple as we can.

Comment: Do I get it right? You say to not answer that question now as it will answer itself in the future?

Comment: Apart from possibly http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-graphical-bitcoin-wallet-for-ubuntu-integrates-with-the-system-notify-osd, none of the questions tagged with [tag:ubuntu] really warrant that tag, and they should use [tag:linux] in addition or only. Even most of the [tag:linux] questions could really be [tag:unix].

Answer (score 3):

Go with the tag(s) that express your requirements.

Most software for Windows will run on Windows 7 64-bit Home Premium. So you should just go with [windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows), and the question will be equally applicable to anyone running most versions of Windows.

You should use a more specific tag if you have a more specific requirement. For example, if you have an old box running Windows 2000 that you're using to drive your $100k experimental setup, and you need software that's compatible with it, tag your questions [windows-2000](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-2000).

Comment: I would argue to leave specific needs _out_ of tags, and enumerate them in the question instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use generic tags. These are for quick filtering. Specify the versions in the post body.

In the MS Windows example, this means that these are your tags:

- [windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows)
- [windows-phone](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone)
- [windows-mobile](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-mobile)

In the case you *really* ask about, say, Windows 3.1, just invent something like [antique-windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antique-windows) ;-) Assume [windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) talks about mostly contemporary versions.

Comment: While I agree with the generics, I cannot approve of those inventions. If you really need something that specific, say so in your question's body. So: no vote, as I can't up- and down-vote at the same time :)

Answer (score -3):

For operating systems with as many versions of Windows, we should only go into the depth of the version, type, and architecture if necessary, such as [windows7-x84-homepremium]. For Macs we should just use [osx] and if the version is absolutely necessary [osx-10-9-1] for Mac OS X 10.9.1.